# Intranet Usernames will have different string representing them

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an Intranet asp.net mvc web application. And I am getting different Username formats from different classes. For example on a Create Post action method I am getting the username for the current login user, and assign it to the CreatedBy field as follow:-

```
public ActionResult Create(Group group)
        {try
            {if (ModelState.IsValid) {
Group.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    repository.InsertOrUpdateGroup(group);
                    repository.Save();
                    repository.InsertOrUpdateAudit(auditinfo);
```

The User.Identity.Name will be something such as :- `domainname\username`

While if on another action method I want to retrieve a list of all Active directory usernames and I use the following:-

```
List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV"))
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context))) {
var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();
foreach (Principal p in searchResults) {
DomainContext dc = new DomainContext();
dc.DisplayName = p.DisplayName;
dc.userGuid = p.UserPrincipalName;
```

Then the UserPrincipleName will be `user1@domainname.local` and not `doaminname\username`. So in this way I will have different strings representing the same active directory user. 
So is there a way to make all usernames standard, regardless of the method I am assigning or retrieving them ?

Answer (score 1):

The are no properties that expose user names in the format "domain\user" so you need to do it your self, and for that, the SamAccountName property is the one to use.

```
 var username = "WIN-SPDEV\\" + p.SamAccountName;
```

**Edit**

To clarify, this applies to search results from the Active Directory, so this will unify the way user names are displayed.

**Your Code will Become**

```
List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV"))
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context))) {
var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();
foreach (Principal p in searchResults) {
DomainContext dc = new DomainContext();
dc.DisplayName = p.DisplayName;
dc.userGuid = p.UserPrincipalName;
var username = "WIN-SPDEV\\" + p.SamAccountName;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,,, but using "User.Identity.Name" will return usernames as domain\user .

Comment: @johnG that's true for the logged in user, i thought you wanted to query their names from the active directory

Comment: and here is the problem. so in case i want to compare two values. they might refer to the same user but have different format...

Comment: @johnG with the solution above they will be in the same format :)